# Split string into array Shellscript

Tags: arrays, shell

How can I split a string into array in shell script?

I tried with `IFS='delimiter'` and it works with loops `(for, while)` but I need an array from that string.

How can I make an array from a string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
str=a:b:c:d:e
set -f
IFS=:
ary=($str)
for key in "${!ary[@]}"; do echo "$key ${ary[$key]}"; done
```

outputs

```
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
4 e
```

---

Another (bash) technique:

```
str=a:b:c:d:e
IFS=: read -ra ary <<<"$str"
```

This limits the change to the IFS variable only for the duration of the read command.

Comment: It doesn't work. Error message say expected "(" in the line where it is ary=($str).

Comment: This is specifically bash syntax. What shell are you using? If you script has `#!/bin/sh` change to `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: how do you invoke your script?

Comment: i don't understand (how am i running this?)

Comment: yes, do you run `sh myscript`? You should not be seeing an error with this code.

Comment: what should I do if I have to use #!/bin/sh

Comment: @SJunejo, the only array-like data structure in /bin/sh are the positional parameters: `set -- $str; for element in "$@"; do echo $element; done`. If you really need an array, you need to choose a different tool for the job.

Comment: The only "array" in shell (not bash) is $@ which can be set with set.

Comment: Doesn't work for me --> 3: backup.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: Arrays are a bash feature. You can't use `sh` if you want arrays. As you should have figured out if you had read the other comments.

Answer (score 28):

```
#!/bin/bash

str=a:b:c:d:e
arr=(${str//:/ })
```

OUTPUT:

```
echo ${arr[@]}
a b c d e
```

Answer (score 8):

Found a solution that doesn't require changing the IFS or a loop:

```
str=a:b:c:d:e
arr=(`echo $str | cut -d ":"  --output-delimiter=" " -f 1-`)
```

output:

```
echo ${arr[@]}
a b c d e
```

Comment: for ELEMENT in $(echo 'a,b,c' | cut -d ',' --output-delimiter=' ' -f 1-)  
do  
    echo "$ELEMENT"  
done

Answer (score 3):

Combining the answers above into something that worked for me

```
set -- `echo $PATH|cut -d':' --output-delimiter=" " -f 1-`; for i in "$@"; do echo $i; done
```

gives

```
# set -- `echo $PATH|cut -d':' --output-delimiter=" " -f 1-`; for i in "$@"; do echo $i; done
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
#
```

Comment: Using $PATH for a test string is a nice touch, but: way too complicated, and how does this differ from, e.g, [zzk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13784224/3789665)?

Comment: @greybeard tl;dr It doesn't :) - I found zzk's answer did not quite work for me so adjusted it by the `set --`  and then collate with useful stuff from the multiple answers given. This was for my own purposes but also share back if others had the same issue

Comment: FWIW I needed to run multiple tests against all folders listed in the path - mainly for auditing against privilege escalation issues.